# JQuery Disable Submit button until Div class result is empty

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a div that display an error message that validates a tons of checkboxes.

```
<div class="result" style="color:red;"><br>Check 2 more for Alberta Hairstylist<br>Check 2 more for Atlantic Hairstylist</div>
```

Now what I want to do is to disable my submit button if the div contain something like the example above. And enable the submit button if the div looks like below

```
<div class="result" style="color:red;"></div>
```

I know there are better ways of validation I just need to patch this up. As quickly as possible.

Still a Jquery newbie, Thanks!

Comment: Don't enable/disable the button based on the contents of the error box - do it where the error is being set, makes your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could add the disabled attribute to your submit button and remove that attribute once your validation is okay.

Something like this;

```
$('#yourSubmitButtonId').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Edit:

It seem more appropriate to use prop()
http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Should use `prop()` for disabling

Comment: Why would `prop()` throw an error on IE6, 7 & 8 (unless you're using jQuery 2.0, which does'nt support old IE) ?

Comment: because IE throw security error on input type modification from HTML (if it existed)
see: http://api.jquery.com/prop/ for more information on that matter

Comment: @Happyninja - that's only for the `type` attribute, for instance when changing from `type="text"` to `type="button"`, not when changing other properties, like `disabled`.

Answer (score 1):

Disables the button if `.result` is not empty :

```
$('button').prop('disabled', function() {
    return $.trim( $('.result').text() ) != "";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use this

```
if($('.result').text()=='') $('button').prop('disable',true);
```

or instead of disabling you can just return false on

```
$('button').click(function(){
  if($('.result').text()=='') return false;
  else // do your stuff
});
```